# PHP format numbers hiding zeros

Tags: php, numbers, format, hide, zero

In order to fill a tab with lots of values, I would like not to display values which are equal to '0'.

For example, instead of having :

```
Test USER   1   0   1   0
Sample USER 1   0   1   0
```

I'd like to have :

```
Test USER   1       1   
Sample USER 1       1
```

I display my values using `printf("<td>%d</td>", $value);`

I've even tried `printf("<td>%0d</td>", $dl_ends[0]);`

Thanks

Comment: Do a `var_dump($value);` to see this variable's content. `printf("%d", 0);` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
printf("<td>%d</td>", $value != 0 ? $value : '');
```

**EDIT**

If you also need to catch empty strings, you can use the following code

```php
printf("<td>%d</td>", $value != 0 && $value != '' ? $value : '');
```

Comment: Thanks JackPoint but this won't solve the problem as it'll give an empty string to be formated as a number -> 0 appears. The other way is the following even if it doesn't allow number formatting : `printf("<td>%s</td>", $value != 0 ? $value : '');`

Comment: Added a second code example that check for an empty string. Does this fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><?php $value ? printf("%d", $value) : ''; ?></td>
```

Comment: `<td><?php $value != 0 ? printf("%d", $value) : ''; ?></td>`
would be better, no ?

Comment: if `$value` is 0, FALSE or NULL then the second statement would be executed, anything other than those values and the first would be executed, although your way would also work

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve my problem : 
`printf("<td>%s</td>", $value != 0 ? $value : '');` which avoid number formatting, or
`$value != 0 ? printf("<td>%d</td>", $value) : printf("<td></td>");` which is longer but more precise.